# Problem getting full path of a shell script while using TCSH

Tags: shell, tcsh

I am using tcsh and I am trying to get path of current shell script without success.

My script contains:

```
echo $0
```

source tmp.csh returns

/usr/lbin/tcsh

```
dirname $0
```

returns /usr/lbin

Answer (score 4):

Use `$_` (save it in a variable as the first thing the script does) instead of `$0`.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set called=($_)
if ("$called" != "") then
    echo "sourced $called[2]"    # the script was sourced from this location
endif
if ("$0" != "tcsh") then
    echo "run $0"                # the script was run from this location
endif
```

**Edit:**

Perhaps in your `.cshrc`:

```
set basepath=/path/to/base
source "$basepath/scriptname" "$basepath"
```

and in your base script:

```
source "$1/subscript"
```

Unless the base script is in your `$PATH`, in which case you're just making things difficult on yourself.

Comment: The first echo returned nothing. It printed just "called"

Comment: @Sam: if you run it (e.g. `./script.tcsh`) that's what it will do. If you source it, it will echo the location (I am deleting that line since it's confusing.)

Comment: That works. But now i want to source the file through .cshrc. In that case $_ is empty and i am not able to get the path. What would be the solution to get path in that case?

Comment: @Sam: It's better to write your script so it doesn't need to know where it's run from. If you're trying to load a configuration file from the same location, for example, the correct way to do that is to put the file in a fixed location and reference that. The usual way would be to put it in `/etc/somedir` or `$HOME/somedir` or something similar. Why is it that you need to know where the script is?

Comment: I agree. But still there is a problem. I am going to call a standard base script through .cshrc. That base script is internally going to call some other scripts in the same directory and sub directories. For sourcing those other scripts i need the path of those scripts in the base script. I can put fixed path in .cshrc, but i dont want to put fixed path in base script. I want a relative path. I know it is complicated, but that's the way we want it.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for you prompt replies. But after doing that i tried to echo $1 in base script and it prints out to be empty.

Comment: @Sam: If you `source "$basepath/scriptname" foo` from `.cshrc` and in `scriptname` do `echo $1` is that also empty? It works for me.